# What college education could help an experienced executive climb the ladder?

Tags: career-path, education

I’m an executive in digital marketing for a Fortune 100. I have 14 years of experience. But I am a college drop out. To grow in my career I’m competing with highly educated people.

What are my options academically to add to my resume?

Comment: Country may be relevant. This question is not really on-topic here. Regardless, masters tend to be the most relevant for managers, either in business or perhaps in a more technical discipline if that's useful for digital marketing. Many masters programs will admit you based on your experience and don't require a college degree. Best option is to find a program you like and talk to their admissions staff.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 14 years experience, academic achievements are almost irrelevant.

Instead, look at professional certifications, experience managing teams or projects, business achievements etc. as these are what others will look at.

You could go for an MBA - that could be appropriate at the level you are at, but it may not be worth the time and money to go through it. I looked at an MBA 15 years ago and it didn't have anything then that I couldn't get from other avenues. I have revisited the decision now I am looking at some more Director roles, and while it is a bit more tempting, it doesn't give me much for the time and money, whereas my professional certifications and board roles are much higher value to me.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution seems to be getting an MBA.

There're a lot of MBA programs that offer night/weekend classes so you don't have to abandon your current career trajectory to get the degree.  They'll often try to charge you more since they assume that you'll have the cash, but it may still be a net win for you.

There're also online MBA programs.  These are similarly convenient in that you might retain your current career while earning the degree.

You might check to see if your current employer offers educational assistance.  Some might help pay tuition for you!

Finally, if an MBA isn't right for you for whatever reason, you could also look into doing a Business degree at a local community college first.  I wouldn't usually recommend it as an MBA seems like the better solution, though it's still an option that may be available to you.

Comment: I agree MBA is likely a good answer.  Do MBA programs admit college drop-outs, or would completing a BA first be required?

Comment: @GEdgar Luckily for 'em, no BA would necessarily be required since many of these programs are tailored for current executives to get a degree like the OP's interested in.  For example, [from MIT](https://emba.mit.edu/admissions/faq/):  **"_Candidates usually hold undergraduate degrees and have at least ten years of work experience. We will consider candidates without undergraduate degrees or with fewer than the recommended years of experience if they have demonstrated exceptional capabilities through other endeavors._"**.